# Go. Не отображает текст, Проблема с HandleFunc

Tags: golang, веб-сервер

Просто показывает : "404 page not found". Не отображает текст : "Hello".

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    conn := http.ListenAndServe(":3030", nil)
    if conn != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR")
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/", mainPage)
}
func mainPage (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Обработчики должны регистрироваться **до** запуска
сервера, а ошибки — верно обрабатываться.

```golang
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", mainPage)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":3030", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("listening error: %s", err)
    }
}

func mainPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    _, err := io.WriteString(w, "Hello")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("writing error: %s", err)
    }
}
```